# MySQL using temporary/filesort

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

This issue baffles me. I really don't understand how a simple query can trigger a temporary table and perform so bad

```
SELECT Urls.*
FROM urls Urls 
INNER JOIN categories_urls CategoriesUrls ON Urls.id = CategoriesUrls.url_id
INNER JOIN categories Categories ON Categories.id = CategoriesUrls.category_id
WHERE Categories.id = 450 
AND Urls.removed = 0 
AND Urls.adult = 0 
AND Urls.id <> 1561806 
ORDER BY Urls.sj_score DESC, Urls.average_rating DESC, Urls.num_reviews DESC 
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 0
```

[image]

Urls has 1.2M rows
Categories 1k rows
CategoriesUrls 44k rows

How the index needs to be so the temporary table is not created? I have several similar simple queries with the same problem.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no problem here, whatsoever, zero, nada. Where did you even read that `using temporary` means there's a problem?

Comment: @N.B., so why this query, when removing ORDER BY, temporary/filsort gone, it's x10 faster?

SELECT IFNULL(SUM(UrlAnswers.num_votes), 0) AS `votes`, COUNT(UrlAnswers.id) AS `num_answers`, UrlQuestions.*, Authors.*
FROM url_questions UrlQuestions 
LEFT JOIN url_answers UrlAnswers ON UrlAnswers.removed = 0 AND UrlQuestions.id = UrlAnswers.question_id
INNER JOIN users Authors ON Authors.id = (UrlQuestions.author_id) 
WHERE UrlQuestions.url_id = 851934 
AND UrlQuestions.removed = 0
GROUP BY UrlQuestions.id
ORDER BY votes DESC, num_answers DESC, UrlQuestions.created DESC
LIMIT 10

Comment: First, no one will read the query you posted in a comment. Second, `using temporary;using filesort` does not indicate a problem. When you ask database to give you data, in a certain order, it has to **PULL** the data, **ANALYZE** the data and **ORDER** the data. You didn't even bother to research what `using temporary` means, can you understand how bad that is? You **assumed** it's bad because your query is slow. Your query is slow for multiple reasons. This is an XY problem. Google it. Ask the question about your **real** problem (slow query), not about your perceived "solution".

Answer (score 0):

If the engine read the tables in the order (categories, categories_urls, urls), no index will help you to avoid the "filesort".

You can try to force the execution order with a `STAIGHT_JOIN`:

```
SELECT Urls.*
FROM urls Urls 
STRAIGHT_JOIN categories_urls CategoriesUrls ON Urls.id = CategoriesUrls.url_id
WHERE  CategoriesUrls.category_id = 450 
AND Urls.removed = 0 
AND Urls.adult = 0 
AND Urls.id <> 1561806 
ORDER BY Urls.sj_score DESC, Urls.average_rating DESC, Urls.num_reviews DESC 
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 0
```

With indexes on `urls(adult, removed, sj_score, average_rating, num_reviews, id)` and `categories_urls(url_id, category_id)`

(Note that I removed the `categories` table from the query, since you can use `CategoriesUrls.category_id = 450` to filter the category.)

The more urls belong to the specified category, the faster this query will find 4 rows and stop the execution. But if there are not enough rows, the query might perform even worse than your original one.